# Implement live markdown rendering using slate.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markdown, slatejs

I'm writing a markdown text editor using [slate.js](https://github.com/ianstormtaylor/slate). I'm trying to implement the following live-rendering effect (from [Typora](https://typora.io/)):

[image: Live Markdown rendering]

As you can see,

1. When I'm typing, the text is turning to bold automatically.
2. When I hit the space key, the four asterisks disappeared, only the text itself is visible.
3. When I focus the cursor back to the text, the asterisks shows up again (so I can modify them).

I've already implemented the first item thanks to the example of [MarkdownPreview](https://www.slatejs.org/examples/markdown-preview), here is the code of it (take from [the slate repository](https://github.com/ianstormtaylor/slate/blob/main/site/examples/markdown-preview.tsx)):

```js
import Prism from 'prismjs'
import React, { useCallback, useMemo } from 'react'
import { Slate, Editable, withReact } from 'slate-react'
import { Text, createEditor, Descendant } from 'slate'
import { withHistory } from 'slate-history'
import { css } from '@emotion/css'

// eslint-disable-next-line
;Prism.languages.markdown=Prism.languages.extend("markup",{}),Prism.languages.insertBefore("markdown","prolog",{blockquote:{pattern:/^>(?:[\t ]*>)*/m,alias:"punctuation"},code:[{pattern:/^(?: {4}|\t).+/m,alias:"keyword"},{pattern:/``.+?``|`[^`\n]+`/,alias:"keyword"}],title:[{pattern:/\w+.*(?:\r?\n|\r)(?:==+|--+)/,alias:"important",inside:{punctuation:/==+$|--+$/}},{pattern:/(^\s*)#+.+/m,lookbehind:!0,alias:"important",inside:{punctuation:/^#+|#+$/}}],hr:{pattern:/(^\s*)([*-])([\t ]*\2){2,}(?=\s*$)/m,lookbehind:!0,alias:"punctuation"},list:{pattern:/(^\s*)(?:[*+-]|\d+\.)(?=[\t ].)/m,lookbehind:!0,alias:"punctuation"},"url-reference":{pattern:/!?\[[^\]]+\]:[\t ]+(?:\S+|<(?:\\.|[^>\\])+>)(?:[\t ]+(?:"(?:\\.|[^"\\])*"|'(?:\\.|[^'\\])*'|\((?:\\.|[^)\\])*\)))?/,inside:{variable:{pattern:/^(!?\[)[^\]]+/,lookbehind:!0},string:/(?:"(?:\\.|[^"\\])*"|'(?:\\.|[^'\\])*'|\((?:\\.|[^)\\])*\))$/,punctuation:/^[\[\]!:]|[<>]/},alias:"url"},bold:{pattern:/(^|[^\\])(\*\*|__)(?:(?:\r?\n|\r)(?!\r?\n|\r)|.)+?\2/,lookbehind:!0,inside:{punctuation:/^\*\*|^__|\*\*$|__$/}},italic:{pattern:/(^|[^\\])([*_])(?:(?:\r?\n|\r)(?!\r?\n|\r)|.)+?\2/,lookbehind:!0,inside:{punctuation:/^[*_]|[*_]$/}},url:{pattern:/!?\[[^\]]+\](?:\([^\s)]+(?:[\t ]+"(?:\\.|[^"\\])*")?\)| ?\[[^\]\n]*\])/,inside:{variable:{pattern:/(!?\[)[^\]]+(?=\]$)/,lookbehind:!0},string:{pattern:/"(?:\\.|[^"\\])*"(?=\)$)/}}}}),Prism.languages.markdown.bold.inside.url=Prism.util.clone(Prism.languages.markdown.url),Prism.languages.markdown.italic.inside.url=Prism.util.clone(Prism.languages.markdown.url),Prism.languages.markdown.bold.inside.italic=Prism.util.clone(Prism.languages.markdown.italic),Prism.languages.markdown.italic.inside.bold=Prism.util.clone(Prism.languages.markdown.bold); // prettier-ignore

const MarkdownPreviewExample = () => {
  const renderLeaf = useCallback(props => <Leaf {...props} />, [])
  const editor = useMemo(() => withHistory(withReact(createEditor())), [])
  const decorate = useCallback(([node, path]) => {
    const ranges = []

    if (!Text.isText(node)) {
      return ranges
    }

    const getLength = token => {
      if (typeof token === 'string') {
        return token.length
      } else if (typeof token.content === 'string') {
        return token.content.length
      } else {
        return token.content.reduce((l, t) => l + getLength(t), 0)
      }
    }

    const tokens = Prism.tokenize(node.text, Prism.languages.markdown)
    let start = 0

    for (const token of tokens) {
      const length = getLength(token)
      const end = start + length

      if (typeof token !== 'string') {
        ranges.push({
          [token.type]: true,
          anchor: { path, offset: start },
          focus: { path, offset: end },
        })
      }

      start = end
    }

    return ranges
  }, [])

  return (
    <Slate editor={editor} value={initialValue}>
      <Editable
        decorate={decorate}
        renderLeaf={renderLeaf}
        placeholder="Write some markdown..."
      />
    </Slate>
  )
}

const Leaf = ({ attributes, children, leaf }) => {
  return (
    <span
      {...attributes}
      className={css`
        font-weight: ${leaf.bold && 'bold'};
        font-style: ${leaf.italic && 'italic'};
        text-decoration: ${leaf.underlined && 'underline'};
        ${leaf.title &&
          css`
            display: inline-block;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 20px;
            margin: 20px 0 10px 0;
          `}
        ${leaf.list &&
          css`
            padding-left: 10px;
            font-size: 20px;
            line-height: 10px;
          `}
        ${leaf.hr &&
          css`
            display: block;
            text-align: center;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
          `}
        ${leaf.blockquote &&
          css`
            display: inline-block;
            border-left: 2px solid #ddd;
            padding-left: 10px;
            color: #aaa;
            font-style: italic;
          `}
        ${leaf.code &&
          css`
            font-family: monospace;
            background-color: #eee;
            padding: 3px;
          `}
      `}
    >
      {children}
    </span>
  )
}

const initialValue: Descendant[] = [
  {
    type: 'paragraph',
    children: [
      {
        text:
          'Slate is flexible enough to add **decorations** that can format text based on its content. For example, this editor has **Markdown** preview decorations on it, to make it _dead_ simple to make an editor with built-in Markdown previewing.',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    type: 'paragraph',
    children: [{ text: '## Try it out!' }],
  },
  {
    type: 'paragraph',
    children: [{ text: 'Try it out for yourself!' }],
  },
]

export default MarkdownPreviewExample
```

My question is, how can I implement the second and third items? I've been thinking about it for a long time, but didn't find any good way to achieve them.

Comment: Did you get any answer?

Comment: @MohanKrishnaSai No.

Comment: Are you flexible to any solution or must using slate.js?

Comment: So the question is basically "can someone implement this for me for free?". You really need to put in some work yourself or at least show that you've made an attempt. And no, copy-pasting that example from github does not count. You can come back when you have a more specific question.

Comment: @AtikurRabbi Currently I'm using `slate.js` as my text editor's framework because it's flexible and powerful. But if you have better solutions to implement a real-time text editor like Typora or obsidian, I'm happy to know.

Comment: I have managed to pull this off using Prosemirror. You can see the demo here https://zuunote.com

Answer (score 0):

**The good news:**

- The original text is saved unharmed (somewhere in your application)
- `Slate.js` is rendering a new element for each style. thanks to the live demonstration link you've posted it is clear that the DOM is saving the `state` of your markdown (which suggest that we can add manipulations on-top of slate if required)

**The bad news:**

- Implementing an editor is a headache. Using an existing one is not always as intuitive and easy as we expected. That's why I love the [Monaco editor project](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/) so much (a free editable editor that gives me the experience of `VS code` for free? yes please!)

### What we can do?

**the easy way:**

Use Monaco editor in our project. From my experience - it is better in terms of coding and formatting technical texts (and maybe this is the engine behind `VS code`)

**The not-so-easy way:**

We can make a simpler implementation - a panel with the raw text and another panel for preview (by the way - this is exactly what happens when you edit markdown files in `VS code` anyways). That way we can always render the view to reflect our most recent changes. For starters - you can use [this project](https://github.com/hanford/remark-slate) to do it and add tweaks to it so suit your demands

**The hard way:**

Using `slate.js commands` (read [this doc](https://docs.slatejs.org/v/v0.47/guides/commands-and-queries) for the general concept + useful examples). This approach will let slate handle the load but requires you to deep-dive into that project as well. Note that you can register custom commands and queries to suit your need without breaking your work pipeline (read [this](https://docs.slatejs.org/v/v0.47/slate-core/editor#registercommand))

**The insane way**:

Try to override slate by using custom events on-top of rendered elements. This can be tricky but achievable if you love to play with projects internals and inject values on the fly. Not very recommended though

### My Recommendation

Create a custom command that will apply the `markdown style` you want (for instance: **bold**)

Use slate handler for tracking the `space` key hit and use your command

```
function onKeyDown(event, editor, next) {
  if (event.key == 'Enter') {
    // TODO: add markdown style 
    editor.applyMarkdownBold() // applyMarkdownBold is a made-up name for your custom command
  } else {
    return next()
  }
}
```

I know - this example will apply **bold** style to all text but - if you combine it with a `range selection` you will get the style you need for the relevant area in you editor (again - [docs](https://docs.slatejs.org/v/v0.47/slate-core/range) for the rescue)

From this point - applying a specific selection via key press or adding the markdown characters by clicking it (using an event + query + command) is only a matter of time

Comment: For your recommendation, how to hide and show the asterisks as in my question's image?

Comment: Thanks for recommending Monaco Editor, I didn't know it before. It's a good candidate for a code editor, but is it a good candidate for a real-time text editor? In the text editor, I want to show the header with a larger font size, I even want to display images and tables as well, VSCode doesn't seem to be able to do it, I doubt if Monaco Editor can.

Comment: to your question: both editors can handle images or pretty much anything else when extended properly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59239118/display-an-image-in-monaco-editor-hoverprovider

Comment: **to your question:** if you select a specific word instead of hover, you can get the value like this https://github.com/ianstormtaylor/slate/issues/551.  from there you can get the `blocks` property (as demonstrated here https://docs.slatejs.org/v/v0.47/walkthroughs/applying-custom-formatting) and apply your logic (such as - append value with proper markdown characters)